# Python won't recognize object parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    def function(objectA_list):
         for objectA in objectA_list:
              str = objectA.attr1
```

objectA.attr1 is not recognized. objectA is an instance of a class in another file that I have imported. How do I "cast" objectA variable as an objectA so I could use access the underlying attribute?

Comment: "casting" doesn't make sense in a language with dynamic typing. Python *variables do not have a type to cast*. Python is dynamically and strongly typed, you create a new object from another object explicitly through some constructor or other. In any case, you must provide a [mcve]. Whatever is in `objectA_list` appears not to be an instance of the class you presumed, which you could elucidate through basic debugging. More accurately, you simply know that this object lacks that attribute, which could occur for various reasons other than not being an instance of that class.

Comment: IOW: Attribute access occurs dynamically at runtime, this isn't some compiler error telling you that your variable is supposed to be of some type, but it's assuming it's some other type, **because variables do not have types**, so a "cast" here makes no sense. What this error is telling you **is there is no underlying attribute**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python does have types. There is a type(arg) function to tell you the type of "arg". An error is generated for example with "print ‘34’ + 17"

Comment: @Marichyasana of course Python has types, I never said anything to the contrary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Maybe I don't understand what you said in your comments. `"Python variables do not have a type to cast."` and `" because variables do not have types, so a "cast" here makes no sense."`

Comment: @Marichyasana yes python *variables* aren't typed: it is a dynamically typed language, *objects* have well defined types, but you can assign them to any variable you want, and reuse the same variable for objects of different types. I'll admit this may sound like nitpicking, but I think it is an important concept to grok

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I am understanding you now, thanks for the detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be slightly confused with your phrasing or your code.

If we have an instance of a class, it is a real object.

```py
class Dog:
    speak = "woof"

husky = Dog()
```

Therefore if you have access to the reference variable, we can call speak variable inside the object and it will return "woof"

```py
husky = Dog()
print(husky.speak) #woof!
```

If you have a list of objects:

```py
husky = Dog()
labrador = Dog()
pug = Dog()
dogs = [husky, labrador, pug]

for dog in dogs:
    print(dog.speak)
```

the husky, the labrador and the pug will each woof.

The reference variables are only for us - they shouldn't be used as part of a function.

Answer (score -1):

Off the hip, you could pass a reference of the object to the function and then access the underlying attribute of objectA. For example:

```
objectA = Myclass()

def function(objectA_list, objectA):
    for i in objectA_list:
        str = objectA.attr1
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction!